# Some help with labels

Tags: tikz-pgf

Hi I want some help to define the labels (\bar{theta}, \underline{theta}, \bar{u}, \underline{u}, B, G) in this graph. I want something like this:

[image]

It's almost done, as you can see from my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
scale = 1.2,
xmin = 0, xmax = 10,
ymin = 0, ymax = 10,
axis lines* = left,
xtick = {0}, ytick = \empty,
clip = false,
]

\addplot[color = blue, very thick] coordinates {(9,8.25) (0,6)};
\addplot[color = red, very thick] coordinates {(0,3) (6,11)};



\addplot[color = black, dashed, thick] coordinates {(0, 7.67) (6.5, 7.67) (6.5, 0)};
\addplot[color = black, dashed, thick] coordinates {(0, 3) (6.5, 3)};




\node [right] at (current axis.right of origin){$\zeta$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please help us to help you! Extend your code fragment to complete small document (MWE: Minimal Working Example) ...

Comment: Hi... I'm new to the forum. I didn't catch that.

Comment: Hm, you already as some questions, so you not vere new ;-). It is not fun to retype part of code, which you already write. Bear in mind, that this take time to people, which are willing to help you (in their spare time) :-).

Comment: Your document example still not works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As starting point:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines = middle,
xlabel={$\zeta$},
x label style={anchor=west},
%
xmin = 0, xmax = 10,
ymin = 0, ymax = 10,
axis lines* = left,
xtick = {0}, xticklabel={$B$},
ytick = \empty,
clip = false,
no marks,
                ]

\addplot +[very thick] coordinates {(0,4) (9,8)} node[right] {$\underline{u}$};
\addplot +[very thick] coordinates {(0,3) (6,9)} node[right] {$\overline{u}$};

\draw[dashed]   (-0.1,7) node[left] {$\overline{Q}$}  -| (6.7,-0.1) node[below] {$G$};
\draw[dashed]   (-0.1,3) node[left] {$\underline{Q}$} -| (6.7,-0.1);
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edited (1):**
Now all labels are corrected. The MWE now replicate your sketch. Tested with recent version of the MiKTeX with `pgfplots` version 1.18 (and works, result is show above).

**Edited (2):**
Added is x-axis label (which is not shown on sketch, but very unusual written in OP code fragment).

Comment: Thank you very much. But how I set B and G in the x-axis, and underline theta and bar theta in the y-axis? With \pgfplotsset{compat=1.18} I get an error and so I can't reproduce the code.

Comment: @PietroP, ah, instead of zero , you like to have B. Done. What error you got? Testing my MWE this can't hapend. See edited answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. Problem solved. I had to set \pgfplotsset{compat=1.16} instead of 1.18.

Comment: @PietroP, why? Do you not have installed last version of `pgfplots`? It is worth to do this :-).